# jquery timepicker not showing in modal window

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am new to posting questions, if any mistakes apologies in advance. I am unable to get jquery timepicker to appear in the modal window (it appears behind the window), was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on how to resolve this. This is the link in jsfiddle

[https://jsfiddle.net/Lrqcczde/2/]

```
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-
    target="#myModal">Launch Time picker</button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="timepicker">Time Picker</h4>

       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
            <label for="timepicker1">Start Time:</label>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input name="timepicker1" id="timepicker1" readonly="readonly" 
             class="form-control timepicker1">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
          dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
         </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
       </div>
       <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
     </div>
     <!-- /.modal -->
```

Thank you in advance.
Peter

Answer (score 9):

You can add **zindex** option when initialize the timepicker.
this is my solution

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker({ zindex: 9999999});
```

https://timepicker.co/options/

Comment: It works. Thanks.
Salam kenal mas.

Answer (score 4):

You Can Try with This css

```
 .ui-timepicker-container {
      z-index: 3500 !important;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Udara Kasun, I did try this before posting and did not have any  success.

Comment: Please try with ctrl+F5

Comment: Peter, didn't you try above my jsfindle example?

Comment: Thank you Udara Kasun, works well now.  I did change to bootstrap 4 css and this worked, but would use your css method.  Thank you again much appreciated.  Peter

Answer (score 0):

You can try with large value for z-index and its working for my end

```
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget.dropdown-menu {
    z-index: 1700 !important;
}
```