# How to get jquery timepicker to function in a modal?

Tags: jquery, laravel, timepicker

Working with [this](https://timepicker.co/) timepicker and I've tried every possible permutation of zindex listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48455558/jquery-timepicker-not-showing-in-modal-window). Maybe I still didn't get it correct, but none of them seemed to have the desired effect.
I think the bootstrap being used hasn't been updated to 4 which might be an issue as well, but that's not my decision to make.
Modal currently:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('muuda_syndmus') }}" method="post">
{{ csrf_field() }}  
<div id="syndmusModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">                    
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">            

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Muuda</h4>
            </div>
            
            <div class="modal-body">                                                                                                                                                                                                    

                <!-- Nädala valik -->                                                            
                <div id="modal-weekpicker" class="weekpicker form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <p class="heading">Nädal:</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input id="modal-syndmus-nadal" name="modal-syndmus-nadal" type="text"  class="kpv form-control input-sm" value="">                            
                        <small class="error" style="display: none;">Nädala valimine on kohustuslik.</small>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <p class="heading">Kuupäev:</p>                                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" id="modal-syndmus-kpv" name="modal-syndmus-kpv"  autocomplete="off" style="width: 100px;" 
                            placeholder="" class="kpv form-control input-sm" value="">                                                
                    </div>                                    
                </div>

                <div id="staatuse_aja_valik" class="form-group staatuse_lisa_kalendrisse" >
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <p class="heading">Aeg:</p>                                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input id="modal-syndmus-aeg-alg" name="modal-syndmus-aeg-alg"
                        class="form-control timepicker" style="width:45%; text-align: center;"
                        pattern="[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}">
                        <span style="width:5%;">-</span>
                        <input id="modal-syndmus-aeg-lopp" name="modal-syndmus-aeg-lopp"
                        class="form-control timepicker" style="width:45%; text-align: center;"
                        pattern="[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}">   
                    </div>                               
                </div>                    

                <div id="staatuse_meeskonna_valik" class="form-group staatuse_lisa_kalendrisse" >
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <p class="heading">Meeskond:</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select class="form-control input-sm" id="modal-syndmus-meeskond-id" name="modal-syndmus-meeskond-id">
                            <option value="0">...</option>
                            @foreach($meeskonnad as $meeskond)
                                <option value="{{ $meeskond->id }}"
                                    @if( $meeskond->id == old('modal-syndmus-meeskond-id') )
                                        selected="selected" 
                                    @endif
                                >{{ $meeskond->nimi }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>                                    
                </div>

                @if( $can_see_toovihik_markus )
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <p class="heading">Märkused:</p>                                        
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div spellcheck="false" id="modal-syndmus-markused" name="modal-syndmus-markused"
                                class="syndmuse-markus-vormil nagu-input" contenteditable="true"></div>
                        </div>                                    
                    </div>
                @endif                    
                                                          
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="hidden" id="syndmus_id" name="syndmus_id" value="">
                <textarea style="display: none;" id="copy-syndmus-markused" name="copy-syndmus-markused"></textarea>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Tagasi</button>
                <button id="btnSalvestaSyndmus" name="btnSalvestaSyndmus" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="salvesta">Salvesta</button>                  
            </div>
            
        </div>                        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your js code?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur Yep, thanks. Turns out the piece I thought I put in the layout file.. wasn't in it.